# Keep referring URL after 404 page in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I setup a 404 page and it works as it should. I am extracting the "error page" from the URL and using that to create a session since I need to pass it as a variable. My 404 has links to different pages and I would like to keep the referring url all the time even if the following pages exist. For example:

1. www.mysite.com/100
2. 100 does not exist and goes to my 404. The url is shown as step 1.
3. Inside my 404 I have links to other pages likes www.mysite.com/link.php but I want that to be www.mysite.com/100/link.php

How can I accomplish this?

This is how I am passing the variable I need:

```
$page2 = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
$str2 = substr($page2, 1);
session_start();
$_SESSION['DIST']=$str2;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ...what? How can you still have 'existing path' for non-existance files (directories)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $_GET to pass a variable through the URL. Then rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/link.php?redirect_url=100
```

To

```
www.mysite.com/100/link.php
```

Using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/link.php$ link.php?redirect_url=$1
```